# How to do voice recognition in Azure and complete immediately

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition

I use [this example from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python) - Continuous Recognition. However, I need to wait for a long time for the recognition to complete, for example for a 1 hour voice file.

Is it possible to have Azure to complete the recognition immediately? Currently, the rate of the recognition is around 1:1, meaning taking 1 hour to recognize a file of 1 hour. I hope it can be done in 1 mitune (1:60).

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is Darren from Microsoft's Speech SDK team. If you are doing recognition from a WAV file, we attempt to upload audio at twice the "real-time" rate. Therefore, on a good network connection, and if the Azure region of the Speech Service you are using is geographically close to you, the fastest you will be able to transcribe one hour of speech is in half an hour.

What programing language are you using? Your link points to Python. Please have a look at our Python sample code for continuous recognition from a WAV file: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py#L257

Note that if you need to do off-line process of long-duration speech files, a better solution for you would be to use "batch processing" and the REST APIs. SpeechSDK is more targeted for real-time transcription. Read about batch transcription here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription
Samples for batch transcription can be found here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/

Darren

Comment: Hi @Darren, thanks for the detailed answer. I followed the batch example in your [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/batch/python/python-client/main.py) but it still took around 1 hour to transcribe 1 hour of the file, meaning batching processing time is similar. I was expecting much faster. My use case is ad hoc transcription of audio files that I find interesting, so cutting the processing time is important for me, regardless realtime or batch. Does Azure provide such a method so that one hour of recording can be done in a few minutes?

Comment: It is not possible to transcribe one hour of audio in a "few minutes". The fastest transcription speed you will get is with Speech SDK, and it will take at least half the duration of the audio to transcribe a long audio file.

Comment: How can I make transcribe faster? I don’t see the option/configuration to control the transcription speed. Using the example you provided above with the Speech SDK, it still took took the time as long as the duration of the audio file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no options to control speed. When reading a WAV file, the SDK tries to send audio as fast as possible (up to twice "real-time") to the speech service. If you have good network connection and you are using an Azure Region close to you, it should transcribe faster. The content of the audio stream also affects the speed of transcription -- if you have a lot of non-speech content (e.g. music) mixed with the speech that will slow down the transcription a bit.

Comment: the reason that no option to speed up is to prevent the speech service from being overloading? I thought having transcripts immediately is also a valid use case.